# assembly program to sort in special way? help please?

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly

8086 assembly language program that sorts an array as follows:
  smallest value in the array should be placed in the first cell.
  second smallest value  in the last cell.
 third smallest value in  the second cell of the array.
  fourth smallest value  placed in the before-last cell of the
array.
• The above procedure continues until the array is fully sorted.
Note that in the above-described sorting technique, the large values in the initial array
will end up being placed at the middle part of the array

here is my code it sorting but in normal way :

```
org 100h

.MODEL  SMALL
    .DATA
            TABLE   DB      9,2,6,8,5,1  
            B       DB      6 DUP(0)
            VAL1    DB      5
            NL      DB     ' ','$'    

    .CODE

            MOV AX,@DATA
            MOV DS,AX
            LEA BX,TABLE
            MOV DL,VAL1

        LBL1:
            LEA BX,TABLE
            MOV CL,5

        LBL2:
            MOV AL,[BX]
            MOV DL,[BX+1]
            CMP AL,DL
            JB LBL3
            MOV [BX],DL
            MOV [BX+1],AL

        LBL3:
            INC BX
            LOOP LBL2
            MOV DL,VAL1
            DEC DL
            MOV VAL1,DL
            CMP DL,00
            JNE LBL1
            MOV CL,6
            LEA BX,TABLE


              DISPLAY: 

            LEA DX,NL
            MOV AH,09H
            INT 21H
            MOV DL,[BX]
            ADD DL,30H
            MOV AH,02H
            INT 21H
            INC BX 
            INC BX 
            LOOP DISPLAY
            MOV AH,4CH
            INT 21H 






ret
```

Comment: Rather than trying to design a sorting algorithm that works this way, I would recommend a two-stage approach - 1) sort the list in the normal way and then 2) rearrange the sorted list into the desired structure. Trying to do both in one pass might prove a bit challenging even in a higher-level language, and would likely not perform as well...

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
mov cl, val1
```

by:

```
mov cl, [val1]
```

This way it moves the content of val1 (the number 5) to cl. In the code above, it would only move the offset of val1 to cl (the same as lea cl, val1).

Comment: That's not correct for MASM, TASM or JWASM. I don't know another assembler that processes `.MODEL SMALL`.